# Does Latin have an animal-based term for "coward," like "scaredy-cat" in English?

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, animals

In English, a lowbrow way to call someone a coward is to call him or her a "[scaredy-cat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scaredy-cat)" or "[fraidy-cat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fraidy-cat)."  Apparently, somewhere along the way cats got a reputation for being easily frightened.

Does Latin, particularly Classical Latin, have a similar synonym for coward, comparing a cowardly person to an animal of some kind?  Wiktionary doesn't mention one, and I don't see one in [Wikipedia's list of Latin phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(full)) either.

Answer (score 6):

Not quite so vulgar, but deer were thought to be easily frightened and fleeing from danger. In a very poetical way, you see this in Horace's simile (*Odes* 1.23) comparing some girl named Chloe to a fawn for fleeing from his advances:

> Vitas hinnuleo me similis, Chloe,
> quaerenti pavidam montibus aviis
> matrem non sine vano
> aurarum et siluae metu.
>
> nam seu mobilibus veris inhorruit
> adventus foliis seu virides rubum
> dimovere lacertae,
> et corde et genibus tremit.
>
> atqui non ego te tigris ut aspera
> Gaetulusve leo frangere persequor:
> tandem desine matrem
> tempestiva sequi viro.

English taken from [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Odes_(Horace)/Book_I/23):

> You avoid me like a deer, Chloe,
> seeking its trembling mother in the remote mountains
> not without an empty fear
> of the winds and the forest.
>
> For whether the arrival of spring quivered
> with shifting leaves, or whether green lizards
> have moved a bramble,
> it trembles with both its heart and its knees.
>
> Nevertheless I do not pursue you, as a cruel tiger
> or as a Gaetulian lion, to break you:
> Cease to follow your mother—
> at last you are ready for a man.

Although *hinni* were mules, *hinnuleus* could refer to both a small mule or a fawn, especially in Augustan Latin and thereafter. Scribonius even uses it adjectivally with *cervus*.